# Say, pronounce or read?

Tags: meaning-in-context, difference

> How do you **read/say/pronounce** this word?

Are the three words interchangeable in the above sentence? The context being my asking someone else about a word I can’t make the sound of. Which of the three is the best fit and why? (Please explain nuances if there are any)

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm curious to know what word you can't make the sound of!

It seems to me like you want to use ***pronounce*** here. If you can't physically create the sounds of the word because it's too complex or foreign to your native language, that means you are having trouble ***pronouncing the word***. You can also use ***saying the word***, but ***say*** is such a general verb with a wide variety of meanings. It's probably more precise to use ***pronounce*** in this situation.

I wouldn't use ***read*** here, because there are many very difficult words that can be read but not pronounced well. An exception to this would be to ***read aloud***, which means to speak the words as you read them. So you could say something like:

> I am having trouble ***reading*** the words ***aloud***.